# Calculate row results based on values/operators (t-sql)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a database table that contains values (decimal) and operators (nvarchar). The operators are basic (+, -, *, /). For each row,
I would like to perform a calculation based on the values and operators, e.g. for row 1: 1 + 2 + 4.
The original table contains **more than a dozen values and operators**, for this reason, a case when statement seems ineffective to me (does it not get real large?).

[image]

```
CREATE TABLE #CalcTable
(
Value1 decimal(7),
Operator1 nchar(1),
Value2 decimal(7),
Operator2 nchar(1),
Value3 decimal(7),
Operator3 nchar(1),
Value4 decimal(7),
Operator4 nchar(1),
Value5 decimal(7),
Operator5 nchar(1),
Value6 decimal(7),
Operator6 nchar(1),
Value7 decimal(7),
Operator7 nchar(1),
Value8 decimal(7),
Operator8 nchar(1),
Value9 decimal(7),
Operator9 nchar(1),
Value10 decimal(7),
Operator10 nchar(1),
Value11 decimal(7),
Operator11 nchar(1),
Value12 decimal(7),
Operator12 nchar(1)
)

Insert into #CalcTable values(
1, '+', 2, '+', 4, '+', 7, '-', 8, '*', 1, '+', 10, '+', 1, '+', 20,
'-', 2, '-', 4, '+', 12, '+')

Select * from #CalcTable
```

I tried dynamic sql, but shame on me, I could solve it only for a specific row,

```
BEGIN
DECLARE @CalcQuery NVARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Operator1 NCHAR(1)
SET @Operator1 = (select Operator1 FROM CalcTable where 
...); //some row
//more operators
SET @CalcQuery = 'SELECT Value1 ' + @Operator1 + ' Value2 + ... FROM 
CalcTable where ... '; //some row
EXEC (@CalcQuery)
END
```

Is the best way to write an effective case/when query or dynamic sql? Or other way?

Comment: What operators could you have? Just the "basic" ones? `+`, `-`, `*` and `/`? Why do you think a `CASE` **expression** would be ineffective?

Comment: Yes, only the basic ones.

Comment: Does the rule "multiplication/division before addition/substraction" apply?

Comment: Please post the data a text and not images. I cannot visualise your image on my pc. I think that a case statement would be best, event for a dozen operators.

Comment: Hi Thorsten, yes.

Comment: Hi Larnu, the original table contains more than a dozen operators/values, to me it seems, the case/when statement gets out of control.

Comment: Then fix your design, @AGuyCalledGerald . Then you don't have an out of control `CASE`. I *hope* you can't have `NULL` values  too.

Comment: Also, like asked, provide meaningful and useful sample data. Images of data is *not* helpful; especially when it isn't representative of your real data.

Comment: If your operators and operands were rows this would be a lot easier to implement.

Comment: Hi Larnu, unfortunately, yes, but I left that aside ...

Comment: FYI, your `INSERT` statement will generate a *"String or binary data would be truncated in table"* as you try to `INSERT` 4 characters into the column `Operator9` (a minus (`-`), whitespace (` `), carriage return, and line break).

Comment: Do you want SQL Server Arithmetic℠ where `select 30 / 3 / 5; select 30 / ( -3 ) / 5;` give answers and `select 30 / -3 / 5;` is a divide-by-zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following solution evaluate the expression respecting the operator precedence. However, it also opens the door to SQL injection attack. The proper way to do this in production is to use a CLR function or one of the scripting languages integrated with SQL Server (R or Python).

```sql
-- Add a column to hold the result
ALTER TABLE #CalcTable
    ADD Result decimal(7)


DECLARE @Expression         nvarchar(max)
DECLARE @Result             decimal(7)

DECLARE @ParamDefinition    nvarchar(100) = '@Result decimal(7) OUTPUT'

DECLARE cur CURSOR FOR
    SELECT  'SELECT @Result = '
                + CAST(Value1 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator1
                + CAST(Value2 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator2
                + CAST(Value3 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator3
                + CAST(Value4 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator4
                + CAST(Value5 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator5
                + CAST(Value6 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator6
                + CAST(Value7 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator7
                + CAST(Value8 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator8
                + CAST(Value9 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator9
                + CAST(Value10 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator10
                + CAST(Value11 AS nvarchar)
                + Operator11
                + CAST(Value12 AS nvarchar)
            AS Expression
    FROM    #CalcTable
FOR UPDATE

OPEN cur
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Expression

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    
    EXEC sp_executesql @Expression
        , @ParamDefinition
        , @Result = @Result OUTPUT

    UPDATE #CalcTable
        SET Result = @Result
        WHERE CURRENT OF cur

    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @Expression
END

CLOSE cur
DEALLOCATE cur
```

Comment: Nice, I used this solution

Answer (score 2):

Without knowing your expected results, my answer may need a bit of tweaking, but I followed the rule of what would happen if you copy and pasted the concatenated string into SQL Server, which does follow standard order of operations. With that, not sure what [Operator12] really does, so I excluded it. You could add it back in where you need it

My approach is entirely set-based **WITHOUT any cursors, loops, or dynamic SQL**.

### Data Setup

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #CalcTable 
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #tbl_GroupCategory
CREATE TABLE #CalcTable
(
ID INT PRIMARY KEY IDENTITY(1,1),
                    Value1  decimal(36,2),
Operator1  nchar(1),Value2  decimal(36,2),
Operator2  nchar(1),Value3  decimal(36,2),
Operator3  nchar(1),Value4  decimal(36,2),
Operator4  nchar(1),Value5  decimal(36,2),
Operator5  nchar(1),Value6  decimal(36,2),
Operator6  nchar(1),Value7  decimal(36,2),
Operator7  nchar(1),Value8  decimal(36,2),
Operator8  nchar(1),Value9  decimal(36,2),
Operator9  nchar(1),Value10 decimal(36,2),
Operator10 nchar(1),Value11 decimal(36,2),
Operator11 nchar(1),Value12 decimal(36,2)
)


INSERT INTO #CalcTable 
VALUES
(1, '+', 2, '+', 4, '+', 7, '-', 8, '*', 1, '+', 10, '+', 1, '+', 20,'-', 2, '-', 4, '+', 12)
,(1, '+', 2, '+', 4, '+', 7, '-', 8, '*', 2, '/', 0, '+', 1, '+', 20,'-', 2, '+', 4, '+', 19)
,(1, '-', 10, '*', 4, '*', 2, '/', 8, '*', 2, '*', 4, '+', 32, '+', 125,'-', 4, '/', 4, '+', 59)
```

### Non-Looping, Non-dynamic SQL Approach

```
/*Unpivot so it's easier to work with operators*/
;WITH cte_Unpivot AS (
    SELECT 
            *
            ,MultiplyDivideGroupCheck = CASE WHEN Op IN ('/','*')  THEN 0 ELSE 1 END
    FROM #CalcTable AS A
    CROSS APPLY (
    Values
         (01,Value1 ,'+')
        ,(02,Value2 ,Operator1)
        ,(03,Value3 ,Operator2)
        ,(04,Value4 ,Operator3)
        ,(05,Value5 ,Operator4)
        ,(06,Value6 ,Operator5)
        ,(07,Value7 ,Operator6)
        ,(08,Value8 ,Operator7)
        ,(09,Value9 ,Operator8)
        ,(10,Value10,Operator9)
        ,(11,Value11,Operator10)
        ,(12,Value12,Operator11)
    ) AS B(OpOrder,Val,Op)
/*If you have consecutive multiply/divide operators like 'a * b / c', need to calculate them togther before adding back into larger result
This calculates a GroupID to be used for that, it's basically a gaps-and-islands problem*/
),cte_Group AS (
    SELECT *
        ,GroupID = SUM(MultiplyDivideGroupCheck) OVER (PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY OpOrder) 
    FROM cte_Unpivot
),
cte_groupCategory AS (
    SELECT *
        /*Need to identify if it's just normal addition/substraction group or a multiply/divide group*/
        ,IsMultiplyDivideGroup = MAX(CASE WHEN Op IN ('/','*') THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END) OVER (PARTITION BY ID,GroupID)
        /*This is needed to know if we add or subtract the result of the multiply/divide groups*/
        ,SignOfGroup = FIRST_VALUE (Op) OVER (PARTITION BY ID,GroupID ORDER BY OpOrder)
    FROM cte_Group
)

SELECT *
INTO #tbl_GroupCategory
FROM cte_groupCategory

;with cte_groupSum AS (
    SELECT ID
            ,GroupID
            ,GroupSum = 
                CASE WHEN SignOfGroup = '-' THEN -1 ELSE 1 END
                /*Calculate sign +/-*/
                *CASE WHEN COUNT(CASE WHEN Val < 0 THEN 1 END) % 2 = 1 THEN -1 ELSE 1 END 
                /*If multiply 0, then multiply SUM by 0*/
                *MIN(CASE WHEN Op = '*' AND Val = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END)
                /*If divide by 0, multiply by NULL so GroupSum returns NULL*/ 
                *NULLIF(MIN(CASE WHEN Op = '/' AND Val = 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END),0)
                /*Calculate total of multiplication/division*/
                * EXP(SUM(LOG(CASE 
                                /*NULLIF to replace 0's with NULL or else functions will break*/
                                WHEN Op = '*' THEN NULLIF(ABS(Val),0)
                                WHEN Op = '/' THEN 1 / NULLIF(ABS(Val),0)
                                ELSE Val
                END)))
            ,IsMultiplyDivideGroup
    FROM #tbl_GroupCategory AS A
    WHERE IsMultiplyDivideGroup = 'Y'
    GROUP BY ID,GroupID,SignOfGroup,IsMultiplyDivideGroup

    UNION ALL

    SELECT ID,NULL,SUM(CAST(CONCAT(NULLIF(Op,'+'),Val) as DECIMAL(36,18))),IsMultiplyDivideGroup
    FROM #tbl_GroupCategory
    WHERE IsMultiplyDivideGroup = 'N'
    GROUP BY ID,IsMultiplyDivideGroup
)
SELECT ID
    /*If divide by 0 error occurs, row in GroupSum will be null so don't return anything*/
    ,FinalVal = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(GroupSum) THEN SUM(GroupSum) END
    ,DivideByZeroErrorOccurred = CASE WHEN COUNT(*) = COUNT(GroupSum) THEN 'N' ELSE 'Y' END
FROM cte_groupSum
GROUP BY ID

/*Manual calculation to check*/
SELECT ID,SelectStatement = CONCAT('SELECT ID = ',ID,',FinalVal = CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(36,2)) ',STRING_AGG(CONCAT(OP,' ',Val),' ') WITHIN GROUP(ORDER BY OpOrder))
FROM #tbl_GroupCategory
GROUP BY ID
```

### Results:

| ID | FinalVal | DivideByZeroErrorOccurred |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 43 | N |
| 2 | NULL | Y |
| 3 | 136 | N |

### Result Validation Queries

| ID | SelectStatement |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | SELECT ID = 1,FinalVal = CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(36,2)) + 1.00 + 2.00 + 4.00 + 7.00 - 8.00 * 1.00 + 10.00 + 1.00 + 20.00 - 2.00 - 4.00 + 12.00 |
| 2 | SELECT ID = 2,FinalVal = CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(36,2)) + 1.00 + 2.00 + 4.00 + 7.00 - 8.00 * 2.00 / 0.00 + 1.00 + 20.00 - 2.00 + 4.00 + 19.00 |
| 3 | SELECT ID = 3,FinalVal = CAST(0 AS DECIMAL(36,2)) + 1.00 - 10.00 * 4.00 * 2.00 / 8.00 * 2.00 * 4.00 + 32.00 + 125.00 - 4.00 / 4.00 + 59.00 |